# GPS Log binary file using Matlab

Tags: matlab, gps

I have a binary file but in "txt" format , I want to extract the values of this file using Matlab but actually I have no idea how to do this.
Usually I use some software to translate the data to a readable one but it is not working with this file now.
So please does any one have an idea how to do this?
and please step by step.
This is my file :
[GPS binary log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Yif3WDOB-IamUtRVZ1NUhzYTQ/edit?usp=sharing) 
The description of the messages is here :

```
Header
Field #  Field Name    Field Type    Desc                 Bytes    Offset
1        Sync          char          Hex 0xAA             1        0
2        Sync          char          Hex 0x44             1        1
3        Sync          char          Hex 0x12             1        2
4        Header Lgth   uchar         Length of header     1        3
5        Message ID    ushort        Message ID of log    2        4
8        Message Lgth  ushort        length of message    2        8
11       Time Status   enum          Quality of GPS time  1        13
12       Week          ushort        GPS week number      2        14
13       Milliseconds  GPSec         Time in ms           4        16
```

Also you can fine the full document about the description in this link :
[Description document by NOVAtel](http://www.novatel.com/assets/Documents/Manuals/om-20000129.pdf)

This is my simple code :

```
fileID = fopen('test.txt');
A = fscanf(fileID,'%x');
fileID = fopen('dec.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID,'%6.2f %12.8f\n',A);
fclose(fileID);
```

---

I have solved the problem using this code in matlab :

```
fileID = fopen('test.txt');
A = fscanf(fileID,'%x');
fid = fopen('binary1.bin', 'w');
fwrite(fid, A)
fclose(fid);
```

and then using the software NovAtel converter4 to convert the binary to ASCII file and Rinex also .
Many thanks to [Mr.aDonda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2056067/a-donda)

Comment: Have a look at [gpsbabel](http://www.gpsbabel.org)

Comment: I used it but I did not get any result

Comment: I see, this format doesn't seem to be supported. Well then, what did you try yourself? For a question on SO it is usually expected that the poster makes an effort to solve the problem his/herself, and asks when getting stuck. To get you started: Look at `fopen` and `fread`.

Comment: I tried them also but the problem this is the first time I deal with this kind of data.

Comment: So I do know If I have used these commands correctly or not

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean by "txt format". You have a hex dump of the binary file. In that case you'll have to recover the binary first. Read the file as text, use `fscanf` with the `%x` format modifier.

Comment: Then post the code that you have, and describe the problems you've run into. To do so, *edit your question*, do not add a comment.

Comment: I used fscan function and I wrote the result to a file , so I got a decimal now.
and then what to do ?
please have a patient on me.

Comment: I am patient. :-) Seriously: "Then post the code that you have, and describe the problems you've run into. To do so, edit your question, do not add a comment."

Comment: I have edited my post with my simple funny code

Comment: Good, one step further. But what you need is not another text file, this time with decimal numbers, but you need a binary file. Have a look at `fwrite`. :-)

Comment: Super Super Super Super Super Super Super
Thank you a lot I have solved the problem by your help :)

Comment: You have? Great! Didn't expect it yet though. :-) I you think it might be interesting to others, consider posting your solution as an answer.